# Changing graphics mode in grub interactive console (debian/OMV live)

Tags: debian, terminal, grub, debian-installer

I'm attempting to install Open Media Vault (Debian based).
The system boots from CD, but the image takes only top-left corner of the screen and when I select [Install] the image becomes totally messed up. According to `videoinfo`, GRUB *thinks* it is 640x480. But it's 1367*768. So when it starts printing the characters, the lines overlap and produce undistinguishable mess.

That's a "feature" of this old laptop of mine. And I faced already the same when installing Free-BSD based OS. However, in FreeBSD boot loader (boot0?), I was able to simply enter the console and say `gop set 2` which switched screen to 800x600 and everyone was happy, and installation went on.

I do see the same mode #2 as 800x600 in `videoinfo` commnd output — but how do I select it from the command line in GRUB? I read through several pages with commands description, but there doesn't seem to be a way to manually interactively "switch" grub into the mode of choice, or am I missing something?